# substr inside printf not working

Tags: php

I need to limit the number of characters created in a URL, up to 150.

This is my original code:

```
 printf("<td><a href='http://mywebsite.com/%s,&radio=$radio,%s' target=\"_blank\">%s</a></td>",$row['id'], str_replace( $simbolos_reemplazar, "_", $row['name']), $row['name']);
```

And this is what I'm doing, but I limit the text of the link instead of the URL:

```
 printf("<td><a href='http://mywebsite.com/%s,&radio=$radio,%s' target=\"_blank\">%s</a></td>",$row['id'], str_replace( $simbolos_reemplazar, "_", $row['name']),substr($row['name'], 0, 150));
```

It means, if we have this example:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/long_url">Link text</a>
```

I want to limit this :`http://www.mysite.com/long_url`
But the last code is working to this: `Link text`

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: WTF? You cannot shorten an url, then it will not work anymore? You can only shorten the description! Or did I get you horribly wrong somehow? You should explain your issue more clear please.

Comment: It will work. The structure of the URL is domain.com/ID_number,name_of_study. The Url's works already if you have this domain,com/ID_number, (comma included) but the text after is what I need to make shorter. Hope it explains your question

Answer (score 0):

The snippets you posted are very hard to read because they are such long one-liners.  I rewrote them to make them readable, please check that this is in fact a correct representation of the code that you posted:

```
// working
$str = "<td><a href='http://mywebsite.com/%s,&radio=%s,%s' target='_blank'>%s</a></td>";
$s1 = (string) $row['id'];
$s2 = $radio;
$s3 = str_replace($simbolos_reemplazar, "_", $row['name']);
$s4 = $row['name'];
printf($str, $s1, $s2, $s3, $s4);

// not working
$str = "<td><a href='http://mywebsite.com/%s,&radio=%s,%s' target='_blank'>%s</a></td>";
$s1 = (string) $row['id'];
$s2 = $radio;
$s3 = str_replace( $simbolos_reemplazar, "_", $row['name']);
$s4 = substr($row['name'], 0, 150);
printf($str ,$s1, $s2, $s3, $s4);
```

If that is correct, it looks like what is going on is that you are truncating the description, and not the URL.  So this should do what you want:

```
$str = "<td><a href='http://mywebsite.com/%s,&radio=%s,%s' target='_blank'>%s</a></td>";
$s1 = (string) $row['id'];
$s2 = $radio;
$s3 = str_replace( $simbolos_reemplazar, "_", $row['name']);
$s3 = substr($s3, 0, 150); // here we truncate the URL
$s4 = $row['name']; // here we leave the description alone.
printf($str ,$s1, $s2, $s3, $s4);
```